# Combining filters for a Django queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Lets say I have models that look like this:

```
class Sauce(models.Model):
    ...

class Topping(models.Model):
    ...

class Pizza(models.Model):
    sauces = models.ManyToManyField(Sauce, related_name='pizzas')
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, related_name='pizzas')
    geo_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=(('NY', 'New York'), ('IT', 'Italy')))
```

Now, I have an endpoint which accepts URL parameters for filtering the pizza table. For example, one time I might get the following:

```
{
    "sauces": [1, 4],
    "toppings": [4, 7],
    "geo_type": "NY"
}
```

Using this, I would simply filter using the following code:

```
Pizza.objects.filter(sauces__in=url_params["sauces"], toppings__in=url_params["toppings"], geo_type=url_params["geo_type"])
```

And this would work perfectly fine. However, sometimes I might get URL parameters which look like this:

```
{
    "sauces": [],
    "toppings": [4, 7],
    "geo_type": "NY"
}
```

Notice the empty array for the sauces parameter. This means that for this request, I don't care about sauces and it can be anything. Now the query would be something like this:

```
Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__in=url_params["toppings"], geo_type=url_params["geo_type"])
```

Once again, this works as expected. However, the issues is that I have a lot of these fields to filter, and the number of combinations is huge. Is there some to just tell my queryset to ignore a filter if it is an empty array? And if the geo_type is an empty string or null, it should ignore those too. Hopefully I have gotten my point across.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the empty lists, for example by making a helper function:

```
def filter_ignore_if_empty(qs, **kwargs):
    return qs.filter(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v != []})
```

and then filter with:

```
filter_ignore_if_empty(
    Pizza.objects.all(),
    sauces__in=url_params['sauces'],
    toppings__in=url_params['toppings'],
    geo_type=url_params['geo_type']
)
```